# easy way to download google workspace and outlook (os windows 10)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, google-workspace

can anyone help me how can I download the existing files with google business's email id? no of users is just one. I just want to download all the files in google drive, docs, attachments, and email as much as it can be.

I was trying google takeout to export data but from where I will be able to download the exported .zip file will it be stored in google drive ?

can we get the same features in outlook also I want to get rid of my outlook accounts too?

will it allow group mails data too?

thx

Comment: Google Takeout allows you to download .zip files to your computer.

Comment: they sent nothing to me as downloadable link. will it allow group mails data too?

Comment: Inside the .zip file(s) there will be a .mbox file which contains all the gmail emails and attachments

Comment: mailbox i understand but what about the conversation that happened through groupmails.

Comment: @Gantendo each time exports are getting expired. what should I suppose to do now?